# If I pick a random sequence of non-repeating 8 letters, what's the probability that the letters are in alphabetical order?

Tags: probability

For instance, abcdefgz works, but redecfed does not.

Comment: "redecfed" has repeated letters (3 'e's, and 2 'd's). So it's not something that's possible in "If I pick a random sequence of non-repeating 8 letters", and hence not relevant to the probability.

Comment: Would the experiment stop at the first letter that is out of sequence or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that by "non-repeating", you mean "distinct". And by "random" I assume you mean that you're picking a sequence [uniformly at random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) (i.e., all sequences are equally likely).

You can imagine decomposing the process of picking a sequence into two steps: first picking the *set* of $8$ letters, and then putting these $8$ letters into some order. There are $8!$ orderings ([permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)) of these $8$ letters, and all of these are equally likely, and only one of these orderings has the letters in alphabetical order, so the probability that the letters are in alphabetical order is
$$\frac{1}{8!} = \frac{1}{40320} \approx 0.000025$$

Answer (score 5):

Whatever letters we pick, there are $8!$ equally likely orders they could appear in. So the probability they will be in the correct order is $\dfrac{1}{8!}$.